# Can not find module 'firebase-bolt/simulator'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-security, angular-cli

I'm trying to setup a test file for some Firebase security rules written with Firebase-bolt.

I have the `firebase-bolt` package installed via npm.  I've verified that it's in my `node_modules` directory and that it's included in my `package.json`.

I have a Typescript test file `src/app/database.rules.spec.ts` that I'm running with the karma test runner (the app is a brand new Angular2/Angular-cli generated app).   The bare bones file looks like:

```js
import { rulesSuite } from 'firebase-bolt/simulator';

rulesSuite('Rules', (test) => { });
```

This shows an error in both my editor (VS Code) and the test runner output:

> Cannot find module "firebase-bolt/simulator"

I also tried just grabbing `firebase-bolt` directly:

```js
import { rulesSuite } from 'firebase-bolt';
```

This gives the error:

> Cannot find module "firebase-bolt"

I've also tried this:

```js
var simulator = require('firebase-bolt/simulator');
var rulesSuite = simulator.rulesSuite;
```

This gives the error:

> Cannot find module "firebase-bolt/simulator"

I'm able to successfully import and use other libraries in this test file, like `firebase-admin` for example.  But, It's unclear to me why I'm unable to import or require `firebase-bolt`.

Here are some relevant version numbers, in case it's helpful:

- firebase-bolt: 0.8.2
- typescript: 2.0.3
- angular: 2.2.3